# Cannot pass function handle as an argument of a function

Tags: function, matlab, arguments, function-handle

I'm new to Matlab and I'm trying to write custom function in matlab that would take function handle as one of its arguments.
I'm getting this error all the time:

```
Error using subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'function_handle'.
```

Trying to debug I performed following test: I run command `x = fminbnd(@humps, 0.3, 1)`. I proceeded as expected - I got result `x = 0.6370`.
So I created custom function called `train` and I copied ALL the code of function `fminbnd` to the file `train.m`. The only thing that I changed is the name, so that code of functions `fminbnd` and `train` is now identical except for the names.

Now I run both functions with the same argument and the custom function throws error while original `fminbnd` returns correct answer.
Here is the code:

```
>> x = fminbnd(@humps, 0.3, 1)

x =

    0.6370

>> x = train(@humps, 0.3, 1)
Error using subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'function_handle'.
```

Here is header of function `train` (everything else is copied from `fminbnd`):

```
function [xf,fval,exitflag,output] = train(funfcn,ax,bx,options,varargin)
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a `which train` showed me that there is a function in the neural network toolbox of the same name.

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/toolbox/nnet/nnet/@network/train.m  % network method
```

You may be running the nnet train.m rather than the one you think you're running. Are you in the directory containing your train.m? When I made sure I was in the right directory, I got it to work:

```
>> which train
/Users/myuserid/train.m

>> x = train(@humps,0.3,1)

x =

    0.6370
```

Maybe you can name your file something else like `myfminbnd.m` instead?

Comment: And you are right! +1 for you and your answer will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of duplicating the whole `fminbnd` function, try:

```
function varargout = myfminbnd(varargin)
    varargout = cell(1,nargout(@fminbnd));
    [varargout{:}] = fminbnd(varargin{:});
end
```

this will work as an "alias" to the existing function:

```
>> fminbnd(@(x)x.^3-2*x-5, 0, 2)
ans =
       0.8165

>> myfminbnd(@(x)x.^3-2*x-5, 0, 2)
ans =
       0.8165
```

(you can get the other output arguments as well)

Comment: does not matter how I replicate function behaviour, the problem was with the name of the function as @kitchenette pointed out.