# MATLAB integral function fails on documentation example

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use MATLAB's `integral` function on MATLAB R2012b.

The [associated function documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012b/matlab/ref/integral.html) has a clear example

```
% create an anonymous function
fun = @(x) exp(-x.^2).*log(x).^2;

% integrate
q = integral(fun,0,Inf)
```

But when I do this I get;

```
Error using subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'function_handle'.
```

I've seen this appear a view times in random places online, but never found a satisfying answer describing what's going on. Any ideas of how to stop this or what could be causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746977/cannot-pass-function-handle-as-an-argument-of-a-function) answer, you should try checking if you have another `integral` function in a different directory on the path. To do that, type `which integral` in your Command Window. If a different `integral` exists, remove the `integral` function which is not part of the Matlab distribution from the path.

Comment: Bingo bango - integral was defined as a variable in a function being called elsewhere.